# Connection to SQL management server using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sql-server-2005, ssms

What I'am doing wrong here? I mean i got this textview and a button. If i click on the button the textview should change to "Connection success" but my codes doesnt do a thing...Am'I lacking something here? I need help guys :) thanks

Here is my line of code

```
package com.test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     try
     {
         Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
         String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=SC_DEV;integratedSecurity=true;";
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
         Statement s1 = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = s1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tblItems");
         Button btntest=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_test);

         if(rs!=null){

              btntest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    checkconnection();

                }

                private void checkconnection() {
                    TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_test);     
                    txt.setText("Connection Success");

                }


            });


         }

     } catch (Exception e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Well my guess is that rs == null, hence no listener is being set. Can you confirm? Taking out if(rs!=null) would be a quick way to check.

Comment: Also check your LogCat output (and add any errors shown to your question). If you are getting an exception, that's where printStackTrace is writing the details to.

Comment: @NigelK what do mean by taking out if(rs!=null)? You mean deleting it?

Comment: Just temporarily yes. So if the button then works, you know that s1.executeQuery is returning null and is the issue to investigate. If it still doesn't work, then you are most likely getting an exception which is taking you to the catch block (hence have a look in logcat). To be honest, the quickest way for you to debug this would be to set a breakpoint and step through using the debugger.

Comment: @NigelK oh by deleting the if statement the button still doesnt work

Comment: Here is some interesting error i found in the logcat tho

12-03 12:35:19.710: W/System.err(1024): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've found a pertinent error in your logcat:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
```

You need to check the JDBC driver documentation for your SQL server version. In SQL Server 2000, the JDBC driver class is as you have specified. However since SQL Server 2005, the name should be:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

Having said that, your comment below suggests your apk doesn't have contain the driver - the standard android library only has the SQLite database driver. You need to download a suitable driver and import the jar file into your project if you've not already done so. Please see this link for starters:

http://amitku.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/how-to-connect-and-access-sql-database-server-from-android-app/

and you may find this useful if you are testing on an emulator:

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

I regret that's the extent of my knowledge on this issue.

Comment: Still getting that error and this 

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.test-2, /system/lib]]